# pandas global data frame

Tags: python, pandas, global-variables

Why is this code wrong?

Isn't D a global variable?

```
import pandas as pd

D = pd.DataFrame()
D['z'] = [2]


def funz2(z):
    d = pd.DataFrame()
    d['z'] = z
    D = D.append(d)
    print(D)


print(funz2(4))
```

This is the error message

```
In [22]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-68bb930462f5> in <module>()
----> 1 __pyfile = open('''/tmp/py3865JSV''');exec(compile(__pyfile.read(), '''/home/donbeo/Desktop/prova.py''', 'exec'));__pyfile.close()

/home/donbeo/Desktop/prova.py in <module>()
     14 
     15 
---> 16 print(funz2(4))

/home/donbeo/Desktop/prova.py in funz2(z)
     10     d = pd.DataFrame()
     11     d['z'] = z
---> 12     D = D.append(d)
     13     print(D)
     14 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'D' referenced before assignment
```

EDIT: 
If variables are not automatically global. 
Why does it work?

```
x = 3 

def funz(z):
    return z * x

print(funz(4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `funz2` can certainly access the `D` variable that you declared outside of it.

The problem you see is because you have declared another `D` variable local to the `funz` function with the line that starts with `D=`. This local one takes precedence over the other globalish one and thus you get the exception.

What you can do is as Alex Woolford suggests and declare the `D` in the funz function as global using the global statement in effect saying 'see that D there, I don't wanna declare no local D var there I want it to reference that other global one'.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Python variables are not global in scope. This is by design: it would be dangerous if a function could alter variables defined outside the function. Here's a more eloquent explanation: [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

If you want to append rows to D within your function, you could declare it as global:

```
global D = pd.DataFrame()
```

When reading a variable, Python looks in its local scope first and, if it can't find the name there, it'll start to look in the containing scopes.